# converting css transform to zoom and position

Tags: javascript, css, multi-touch, css-transforms, hammer.js

I'd like to do pinch zoom and panning with hardware-accelerated `transform: translate3d() scale3d()` CSS. Once the gesture is complete, I reset the transform and switch to CSS `zoom` and absolute positioning. This way, the zooming and panning is jank-free, and at the end of the gesture it rerenders the content nicely.

Panning works fine if I take the zoom into account:

```
.on('dragend', function(event){
  $pinch.css({
    // Reset transform
    transform: "translate3d(0, 0, 0) "
  });
  // Convert transform to position
  panX += event.gesture.deltaX/zoom;
  panY += event.gesture.deltaY/zoom;
  $("#content").css({
    left: panX,
    top: panY
  });
})
```

But with the pinch zoom I can't figure out how to factor the difference in `zoom`'s origin (0,0) and the gesture's origin (the middle of the pinch).

```
.on('transformstart', function (event) {
  currentZoom = zoom;
  startX = event.gesture.center.pageX;
  startY = event.gesture.center.pageY;
  originX = startX/currentZoom;
  originY = startY/currentZoom;
  $pinch.css({
    transformOrigin: originX+"px "+originY+"px"
  });
})
.on('transform', function (event) {
  scale = Math.max(0.25/currentZoom, Math.min(event.gesture.scale, 6/currentZoom));
  deltaX = (event.gesture.center.pageX - startX) / currentZoom;
  deltaY = (event.gesture.center.pageY - startY) / currentZoom;
  $pinch.css({
    transform: "translate3d("+deltaX+"px,"+deltaY+"px, 0) " +
               "scale3d("+scale+","+scale+", 1) "
  });
})
.on('transformend', function (event) {
  // Convert scale to zoom
  zoom = currentZoom * scale;
  zoom = Math.max(0.25, Math.min(zoom, 6));
  $pinch.css({
    // Reset transform
    transform: "translate3d(0, 0, 0) " +
               "scale3d(1, 1, 1) ",
    zoom: zoom        
  });
  $("#content").css({
    top: currentX + deltaX + ????
    left: currentY + deltaY + ????
  });
})
```

Source: http://bl.ocks.org/forresto/6097596 or http://codepen.io/forresto/full/KBHDr ... shift + mouse drag simulates multitouch. CSS `zoom` doesn't work in Firefox.

Hammer.js' `event.gesture` looks like

```
angle: -133.87669728592456
center: Object
  pageX: 426
  pageY: 337
deltaTime: 853
deltaX: -75
deltaY: -78
direction: "up"
distance: 108.2081327812286
eventType: "end"
pointerType: "touch"
rotation: 0
scale: 1
target: HTMLDivElement
timeStamp: 1375041776946
velocityX: 0.08792497069167643
velocityY: 0.0914419695193435
```

Comment: While I might not be able to answer your question I can give some advice. where possible use classes rather then the jQuery css function. Keeping css in css files rather then JavaScript where possible can lead to much cleaner and more understandable code in my opinion. Also some css3 variables get rather messy when used in JavaScript. so rather then doing animations in JavaScript I would use css3 transitions with timeouts in the JS to match the timing. Not saying yours is bad, just personal experience.

Comment: The `.css()` calls that I'm making are all for dynamic positions. Also, jQuery takes care of the browser prefixes, which is nice.

Comment: Less can as well, witch is nice, just an opinion though, don't think it will really help your problem much.

Answer (score 3):

Modify your code to below

```
var $pinch = $("#pan");
var pinch = $pinch[0];
var currentZoom, startX, startY, originX, originY, scale, deltaX, deltaY, distance_to_origin_x, distance_to_origin_y;
var zoom = 1;
var panX = 0;
var panY = 0;

Hammer(pinch)
.on('transformstart', function (event) {
        currentZoom = zoom;
        startX = event.gesture.center.pageX;
        startY = event.gesture.center.pageY;
        originX = startX/currentZoom;
        originY = startY/currentZoom;
        distance_to_origin_x = originX - $pinch.left();
        distance_to_origin_y = originY - $pinch.top();
        $pinch.css({
          transformOrigin: originX+"px "+originY+"px"
        });
})
.on('transform', function (event) {
        scale = Math.max(0.25/currentZoom, Math.min(event.gesture.scale, 6/currentZoom));
        deltaX = (event.gesture.center.pageX - startX) / currentZoom;
        deltaY = (event.gesture.center.pageY - startY) / currentZoom;
        $pinch.css({
          transform: "translate3d("+deltaX+"px,"+deltaY+"px, 0) " +
                     "scale3d("+scale+","+scale+", 1) "
        });
})
.on('transformend', function (event) {
  // Convert scale to zoom
  zoom = currentZoom * scale;
  zoom = Math.max(0.25, Math.min(zoom, 6));
  distance_to_origin_x *= zoom;
  distance_to_origin_y *= zoom;
  $pinch.css({
    // Reset transform
    transform: "translate3d(0, 0, 0) " +
               "scale3d(1, 1, 1) ",
    zoom: zoom
  });
  $("#content").css({
    top: originY + distance_to_origin_y ,
    left: originX + distance_to_origin_x
  });
})
```

The way this works is by calculating the vector between the origin point of the gesture and the top left corner of the content. When you scale the page that vector should scale linearly with the rest of the page.

The vector is distance_to_origin_x and distance_to_origin_y